# How to generate multiple function names?

Tags: python, naming

I have a number of functions called `func_1`, `func_2`, ... I'd like to call each of them in a `for` loop.

I could do:

```
for f in [func_1, func_2, func_3]:
    print f('foo', 'bar')
```

but I'd like less typing. Is there any way to generate the names, something like:

```
for f in ['func_%s' % range(1,5)]:
    print f('foo', 'bar')
```

This fails with `'str' object is not callable`, but is there anything like this that works?

EDIT: I'm testing a number of alternative versions of `func`. They are all supposed to give the same result, but with different implementations. I control the inputs and this is not in production.

However, this is bad and possibly dangerous practice in other contexts. See the comments and answers.

Comment: Yes, but this is **bad** design. Usually you should give functions an informative name, a *call-by-name* is usually dangerous.

Comment: This is the epitome of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't have to do this in the first place.

Comment: Explicitness, readability, maintainability and testability are very important in software practice. This goes against each of those.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in this context, the names are informative. func_2 is the second alternative version of func. See the edit, as this was not clear from the original question

Comment: @idjaw See the edit. This is for testing alternatives. Therefore, things such as maintainability are less important. I think of a new implementation, then bump `range`.  The tests are not all that complex; if they were I'd be doing something more sophisticated.

Comment: This is unfortunately closed, so I'll post a hint instead of an answer. You could put the functions all in one module, and then do `import alternatives; funcs = [f for f in alternatives where f.__name__.startswith("func")]`. I haven't tested this, the syntax to iterate over a module's contents might be different. This is a bit like how test runners find unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

You could look them up in the local scope:

```
for f in ['func_%s' % range(1,5)]:
    print locals()[f]('foo', 'bar')
```

The [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function returns a dictionary of names to values in the local scope. If they are global functions, use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

Comment: I get `KeyError: 'func_[1]'`

Comment: You copied the incorrect list comprehension from the question. It should be `['func_%s' % i for i in range(1,4)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`. However it is very dangerous to use `eval`. Be careful while playing with it.

```
for f in ['func_%s' % range(1,5)]:
    print eval(f)('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Leaving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) here because friends don't let friends eval.

Comment: @idjaw that's why my comments are there. please read it carefully. Hope u have read it.

Comment: Yes, I did read it. Otherwise I would not have left a comment about it. Did you read my link I left? :)

Comment: @idjaw so why negative rating for this.

Comment: I did not downvote you.

Comment: @idjaw no problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @idjaw In my context (see question edit), `eval` is not dangerous. I know the inputs and it's not in production. Am I missing something?

Comment: @foosion You can do whatever you want. But please keep in mind that these answers help the community as a whole as well. And by accepting answers that are clearly using very bad software practice, it also indicates to other readers that "hey, I can do this too" who don't know better. Keep that in mind too. But, yeah...you can do whatever you want here. :) But, it's also important to indicate to the readers the dangers here too, which is also why I put the link in the comment to help people understand what eval is.

Comment: If you're going to use `eval`, at least use it right - human errors are another reason why using `eval` can go horribly wrong. The current code doesn't work.

Comment: @Rawing Good point. I never use `eval`, for the reasons given here, so I didn't even realize the posted code is wrong.

Comment: guys, i have not tried in my code editor. its about brackets misplacing.  editiing now. it will work now.